# problem While Sharing text in Android using SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am Following this  [link](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/search/label/Shared%20Preferences) to use the SharedPreferences.Am trying to Apply in my Application but The Shared value returns the null value

Here my code To assign the Shared Variable

```
                           SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("pref",Activity.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor= sharedPreferences.edit();
                            String l="hello";
                            editor.putString(l,"imagepath");
                            editor.commit();
```

> here code to access the Shared variable

```
   SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    String prefName = myPrefs.getString("imagepath",null);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"create banner"+prefName,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

> here prefName returns null value.It Cannot Shared.

Answer (score 0):

you are using wrong key.

get string like this:

```
String prefName = myPrefs.getString("hello",null);
```

you are also using two different sharedPreference name:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("pref",Activity.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

Please make sure you write and read in same `SharedPreference`.

Your code to write in SharedPreference should look like this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("pref",0);
SharedPreferences.Editor edito r= sharedPreferences.edit();
String l="hello";
editor.putString(l,"imagepath");
editor.commit();
```

To read from SharedPreference should look like this:

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("pref", 0);
String prefName = myPrefs.getString("hello",null);
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"create banner"+prefName,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Am Changing to SharedPreferences,Again it return the null value Sir

Answer (score 0):

Switch this around:

```
editor.putString("imagepath", l);
```

also you will want to change the possible return value of "null" to a more acceptable error return value, maybe 0 or -1.

```
    String prefName = myPrefs.getString("imagepath","0");
```

Source [Android Doc for Editor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html):

```
abstract SharedPreferences.Editor    putString(String key, String value)
//Set a String value in the preferences editor, to be written back once commit() or apply() are called.
```

Comment: Sir i Declare prefName as String so i Cannot pass integer into the String

Answer (score 0):

The preference name is "hello", not "imagepath".

```
String prefName = myPrefs.getString("hello", null);
```

And I think it's better to use `getString("hello", "")`. This way, `prefName` will never be `null`.

Comment: I think "hello" is the value for "imagepath" key?  So he would need to switch his .putString statement.

Comment: Judging from the way he used `putString`, "hello" is the key and "imagepath" the value.

Answer (score 0):

You have written "myPrefs" in (SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);)

Change it like this (SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("pref", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);)

here i have change "myPrefs" in ("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE) to "pref" .

Now you the coorect one be  ("pref", MODE_WORLD_READABLE)